# Using data from form in JavaScript to save a name

Tags: javascript, forms, frontend, web-component

I am trying to allow the user to send in their nickname, which I will then save and use later on in my JS.

```
const template = document.createElement('template')

template.innerHTML = `
  <div>
  <form id="createName">
    <label for="name">Write your name here:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <button id="confirm">Confirm</button>
  </form>
  </div>
`

class createName extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

  }

  saveName() {
    let nickname = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#name').value
    console.log(nickname)
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#confirm').addEventListener('click', () => this.saveName())
  }

  
}

window.customElements.define('name-form', createName)
```

The form looks right in the browser, so it's something to do when I'm trying to get the actual name. Nothing is console.log-ed, so I'm thinking the saveName() is the issue. I'm unsure of how to get a hold of what the user is actually typing in.

Comment: You never call `connectedCallback` ..? Also, an id of an element in a template is not a good idea.

Comment: `<button type="button"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your Web Component; less code means less potential errors.

Looked to me like you fell in the FORM-auto-submit trap:

```html
<my-form></my-form>

<script>
  customElements.define("my-form", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super().attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).innerHTML = `
      <form>
        <label for="name">Write your name here:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">
        <button>Confirm</button>
      </form>`;
      this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button").onclick= (evt) => {
        evt.preventDefault(); // prevent FORM submit
        let nickname = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input').value;
        document.body.append("You said:" , nickname);
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Excellent help. 

If I want to be able to access that nickname easily outside of this class, am I right in thinking that I could add a field before the constructor, and then setting this.nickname = nickname?

Comment: Yes, its regular JavaScript, the Web Component is an Element/Object just like any other. So ``this.nickname`` is a Property. Or set it as attribute ``this.setAttribute("nickname", nickname)`` if you need CSS styling. Most Web Component Tooling will combine Properties and Attributes as one "setting"